# How can you redirect to login page on put method if the user is not authenticated in express.js?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, express, routes

I want to update a database from angularjs page with $http.put method. 
But if the session expires, it shows me like these on server.

put method hits on this route

```
PUT /api/categories 302 12.381 ms - 46
```

redirected to this page after not being authenticated.

```
PUT /admin/login 404 14.374 ms - 4061
```

The problem is, it doesn't go to login page, instead, it stays on the same page. to redirect it should be GET /admin/login,

Can I convert the method from PUT to GET or,
is there any other workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$http.put`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) is a client-side javascript AJAX call made by Angular to the server.

(302) Redirection can only occur if the request has been made ***by the browser***.

What you need to do is have your the client-side Javascript code *tell* the browser to redirect. Which is done by resetting `window.location`. Do it in the error callback of `$http.put` like this:

```
$http.put(…).
success(function(){
    …
}).
error(function(d,status){
    if(status==404) window.location = '/admin/login';    
});
```

Comment: worked like a charm. btw, why does it redirect for GET and POST method but not for PUT or DELETE methods ? is it not possible to send the 302 status for PUT or DELETE methods ?

Comment: If it's purely an AJAX call it shouldn't redirect *at all*, as redirects are only handled by the browser. Are you saying `$http.post` handles redirect for you but `$http.put` does not? If that's the case I can only imagine you must have some redirection handling logic already in your http.post calls.